# Trying to create login form for username and password, something doesnt work int the form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, authentication

Im trying to develop login form with username and password that have to be verified and match certain requirements. I am struggling with the form, not sure what i am missing,,,also login button doesny show up as button.
Any help appreciated.

```
<body>

<form onlogin="return checkForm(this);">
    <p><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username"></p>
    <p><input type="password" name="pwd1" placeholder="Enter Password"></p>
    <p><button type="login"placeholder="Login"></p>
    <p> <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a></p>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

function checkForm(form)
{
    if(form.username.value == "") {
        alert("Error: Username cannot be blank!");
        form.username.focus();
        return false;
    }
    re = /^\w+$/;
    if(!re.test(form.username.value)) {
        alert("Error: Username must contain only letters, numbers and underscores!");
        form.username.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if(form.pwd1.value != "") {
        if(form.pwd1.value.length < 6) {
            alert("Error: Password must contain at least six characters!");
            form.pwd1.focus();
            return false;
        }
        if(form.pwd1.value == form.username.value) {
            alert("Error: Password must be different from Username!");
            form.pwd1.focus();
            return false;
        }
        re = /[0-9]/;
        if(!re.test(form.pwd1.value)) {
            alert("Error: password must contain at least one number (0-9)!");
            form.pwd1.focus();
            return false;
        }
        re = /[a-z]/;
        if(!re.test(form.pwd1.value)) {
            alert("Error: password must contain at least one lowercase letter (a-z)!");
            form.pwd1.focus();
            return false;
        }
        re = /[A-Z]/;
        if(!re.test(form.pwd1.value)) {
            alert("Error: password must contain at least one uppercase letter (A-Z)!");
            form.pwd1.focus();
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        alert("Error: Please check that you've entered and confirmed your password!");
        form.pwd1.focus();
        return false;
    }

    alert("You entered a valid password: " + form.pwd1.value);
    return true;
}
```

`

Comment: Your button doesn't work because it isn't written correctly. You need to add a body and a closing tag. The onlogin event isn't a DOM event so you cannot expect it to trigger. Add an onclick event to the button instead.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the button is not showing up is because there is no closing tag . Also don't forget to add text between the opening and closing tag.

```
<body>
   <form id="form">
     <p><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username"></p>
     <p><input type="password" name="pwd1" placeholder="Enter Password"></p>
     <p><button type="login"placeholder="Login" onclick="myform()">Login</button></p>
     <p><a href="#">Forgot your password?</a></p>
   </form>
```

Changed the html and added a onclick event to call a function.

```
function myform(){
var form = document.getElementById("form");
checkForm(form);
}

function checkForm(form)
 {
if(form.username.value == "") {
    alert("Error: Username cannot be blank!");
    form.username.focus();
    return false;
}
re = /^\w+$/;
if(!re.test(form.username.value)) {
    alert("Error: Username must contain only letters, numbers and underscores!");
    form.username.focus();
    return false;
}

if(form.pwd1.value != "") {
    if(form.pwd1.value.length < 6) {
        alert("Error: Password must contain at least six characters!");
        form.pwd1.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if(form.pwd1.value == form.username.value) {
        alert("Error: Password must be different from Username!");
        form.pwd1.focus();
        return false;
    }
    re = /[0-9]/;
    if(!re.test(form.pwd1.value)) {
        alert("Error: password must contain at least one number (0-9)!");
        form.pwd1.focus();
        return false;
    }
    re = /[a-z]/;
    if(!re.test(form.pwd1.value)) {
        alert("Error: password must contain at least one lowercase letter (a-z)!");
        form.pwd1.focus();
        return false;
    }
    re = /[A-Z]/;
    if(!re.test(form.pwd1.value)) {
        alert("Error: password must contain at least one uppercase letter (A-Z)!");
        form.pwd1.focus();
        return false;
    }
} else {
    alert("Error: Please check that you've entered and confirmed your password!");
    form.pwd1.focus();
    return false;
}

alert("You entered a valid password: " + form.pwd1.value);
return true;
}
</body>
```

See working version [here](http://codepen.io/mike1477/pen/pEMymK?editors=1010)